# How to handle huge efcore migrations designer files that is slowing down build and IDE

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-core-2.1, entity-framework-core-migrations

I currently have an efcore 2.1 project with about 230 entities and about 350 migrations. Every time i add an efcore migration, a designer file is created. This file is approximately 535 kb and growing (150mb total for alle designer files). This makes the IDE slow and unresponsive, refactoring is a no go, it also makes the build process slower. If i delete all designer files, the build goes down from 110 to 20 seconds, and the IDE gets snappy again.

however, once I delete all designer files, i'm not able to work with the "dotnet ef database" command.

I have also previously merged all migrations. this worked, except there were some issues doing this in a team setting (had to run manual commands on each developer machine, no team members could have any unsynced migrations etc) and it is only temporary as the migrations start piling up again after a while.

I am curious if there are other projects with the same problem, and how they work around this?

Comment: I only see a way out of this: You divide the context into smaller ones, producing smaller migration files. Having 230 entities is pretty a lot.  I'm just intrigued by your statement: "refactor is a no go". How else you expect to improve this? Care to explain why not?

Comment: what i meant to say was that refactoring was a pain, since the IDE was so slow. I can see how that was not a very clear statement :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now, in the future, it's possible to add an `.editorconfig` file to the **Migrations** folder, with the following contents:

```
# All files
# Sets generated code for all migrations
[*]
generated_code = true
```

It will disable all analyzers, which makes my IDE much happier with all the migrations.

Note: requires Visual Studio 16.5

Comment: Hey, this is the accepted answer, but doesn't appear to work for me. We have all migrations in a separate project, and when building either this project or the entire solution, VS tends to take a very long time and MSBuild takes an ungodly amount of resources. I've added a config with your code, but it doesn't appear to make any difference.
EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.4, Visual Studio 16.7.7. Would you have any idea why it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: There are multiple issues with huge migrations in EF Core, this resolves the particular issue with code analyzers processing the generated code unneccessarily. Perhaps you are hitting https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23435 ? I've upgraded to .NET 5 / EF Core 5 and do not experience any issues any more with this.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Unfortunately we can currently not afford to upgrade, as we have more than few client evaluated queries which would break in EFCore 3. However, our largest designer files are still only about 600KB, so nowhere near the 2.5MB reported in the issue you linked. I will try upgrading to 16.8.2 which was also recommend in the linked page. Thanks.

Comment: Update: EF Core 5 made it even worse. Limiting the sdk version to 2.X or 3.X at least allows me to build, but it's still insanely slow and resource intensive. If I exclude the .Designer files the build is fine, but then the eftools commands and actual migrations don't work anymore.

Comment: Do you build with VS2019 16.8.2 or dotnet build? Since the latter has not been patched yet. See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/48897 to track merge process

Comment: VS2019 uses an insane amount of resources, but eventually builds. PowerShell, using the dotnet tool, never makes it. Regardless, it doesn't seem like the update fixed my initial problem, namely resource intensive, slow builds due to a high amount of migrations. It's back to the drawing board on that one.

Comment: Where should we put this file? For example, is on the same directory of the option -o when we are generating a migration ?

Comment: @Camadas in the same folder as you store your migration files

Comment: @joakimriedel I did put the file into the folder where the migration files are generated no diference at all :/

Comment: @Camadas I'm not sure what effect you are looking for, but it will disable analyzers on the generated files.

Comment: @joakimriedel Just trying to make the generation of the migration files more faster, during the development, it takes like 5 minutes to generate the migration files

Comment: @Camadas I see, perhaps there are other issues at play for you except analysers then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use another assemblies to manage migrations.

Comment: How can you give an example please?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to purge your migration files. I sometimes use it to keep the data module small and compilable. You can find [this link](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jan/13/Resetting-Entity-Framework-Migrations-to-a-clean-Slate) useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is a duplicate of [Recommended way to clean old Entity Framework Core migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56803788/recommended-way-to-clean-old-entity-framework-core-migrations) and [Entity Framework Core: Is it safe to delete Migration.Designer.cs if we will never Revert a migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47048721/entity-framework-core-is-it-safe-to-delete-migration-designer-cs-if-we-will-nev). The whole topic is discussed in various answers on these threads.

I suggest to consider my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65004969/331281) in order to get your IDE snappy again and to reduce compilation time. And in the long run, it seems good practice to roll-up all migrations into one from time to time. If this is not urgent in your case, you might want to wait for [this feature](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2174) (planned for .NET 6) that allows you to do so in a simpler way.