# Recommended way to clean old Entity Framework Core migrations

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

After developing our application for a while we've accumulated quite a bit of EFCore database migrations. Since EFCore adds a snapshot of the entire db model to every migration, this code adds up quite a bit. After analysis about 80% of our compile time is spend on the migrations (compiling + Roslyn analyzers).

So it's time to clean up some old migrations! But what's the best way to do this? There doesn't seem to be any official guidance on it...

We don't need any rollbacks (we only roll forward), so that makes things more simple. We do need to support creating a database from scratch, and updating a database from the last few migrations.

What I've tried:

1. The nuclear option seems to be to delete all migrations and the model snapshot, and creating a new initial migration. While this is fine, it seems a bit dangerous. With this approach we need to be *very* careful that every part of the database schema is part of the code model. One edge case we for example ran into is that EFCore doesn't support checked constraints yet. So we added a checked constraint in a migration, but not in the code model. So when creating a new initial migration, the checked constraint was not part of it.
2. As an experiment, I've tried to delete the model snapshot from all old migrations, since the snapshots are 90% of the code which cause the long compile time. I figured out, that EFCore only uses the snapshot as a compare tool to make a new migration. After deleting the snapshot, the old migrations were however no longer executed when they ran on a fresh database.

So is there any better way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: Weird, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47060795/5473409), solution 2 should maybe have worked.

Comment: Just tested if solution 2 works on EFCore 2.0. Ran into the same issue as I described (fresh db not running migrations without Designer file).

Comment: I've created an issue on the EFCore repo for solution 2: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/16331

Comment: First solution works for me but yes, you mentioned a good point when it could be dangerous.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Okay, since asking this question I've experimented quite a bit with this.

It seems for now, the best way to accomplish this is option 1. Option 2 would be much better, but until [this EFCore feature](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2174) is implemented, it's not really doable for my use case (supporting existing dbs with migrations on them, and supporting empty dbs).

Option 1 also has a few pitfalls which I stumbled upon (maybe even more that I haven't stumbled upon).
So this is how I did it:

Create a new initial migration:

1. Make sure all your existing migrations have been applied to your database. We'll create a new initial migration, so the migrations that haven't been applied will be lost.
2. Delete your old EFCore migration files, and the database snapshot file.
3. Create a new Initial migration from your database's current state. (For example via `dotnet ef migrations add Initial-PostCleanup`.)

This new migration is only compatible with new databases, since it will create all tables (and fail if any of the tables, constraints, etc. already exist). So now we're going to make this migration compatible with the existing database:

1. Create a SQL script for the new initial migration via `dotnet ef migrations script -o script.sql`.
2. Remove the first transaction (until the first `GO`), which creates the `__EFMigrationsHistory` table:

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [__EFMigrationsHistory] (
        [MigrationId] nvarchar(150) NOT NULL,
        [ProductVersion] nvarchar(32) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK___EFMigrationsHistory] PRIMARY KEY ([MigrationId])
    );
END;

GO
```

3. Remove the last transaction, that inserts the new entry in the `__EFMigrationsHistory` table:

```sql
INSERT INTO [__EFMigrationsHistory] ([MigrationId], [ProductVersion])
VALUES (N'20190704144924_Initial-PostCleanup', N'2.2.4-servicing-10062');

GO
```

4. Remove `GO` commands, since we will put the create script in an IF statement:
   Replace `GO\r\n\r\n` with nothing.
5. Now open up your migration file (the C# file, not the sql file) and replace the `Up` method with the following:

```cs
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.Sql(@"
DECLARE @migrationsCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[__EFMigrationsHistory])
IF @migrationsCount = 0
BEGIN
    % PASTE YOUR EDITED SQL SCRIPT HERE %
END
");
}
```

Done! Everything should work now!

Be sure to compare the database schema, and data before and after for the new database. Everything that's not part if your EF Code model is not part of the new database.

Comment: Works perfectly, be sure to re-add custom scripts from old migrations. For example I had to add the code for creating a view which would otherwise not exist when creating a new database.

Comment: Maybe one pitfall when using this solution: you will lose database independence as the copied SQL is now specific to your database type.

Comment: Any reason why one wouldn't just a.) delete the migrations b.) create initial and c.) remove all but first item in __migrationhistory in database table, and update the first record to have the right name and hash , as prescribed in the snapshot?

Comment: @Barry Do you mean doing only those 3 things instead of all the things I described in the answer? Or do you mean something more specific?

Comment: Yes exactly, just curious. Because that works for me, wasn't sure if that leaves something out of the picture fatally; such as indexes, constraints, etc? Thank you in advance! really appreciate the reply

Comment: Well, haven’t tested in and it’s been a while. But the main issue was making sure the new migration doesn’t try to recreate tables if they already exist. I assume you’re doing step c manually on the db, instead of via a migration, right? If that’s fine for you then your solution seems perfectly fine. I had the constraint that I couldn’t (and didn’t want to) modify the production database manually.

Answer (score 8):

A bit late, but we had the same problem in our current project. Above 400 migraitons and 6m lines of code inside .Designer. Here is how we managed to resolve this problem:

*MigrationProject.csproj*

```
  <PropertyGroup>
     ...
     <DefaultItemExcludes Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">$(DefaultItemExcludes);Migrations\**\*.Designer.cs</DefaultItemExcludes>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This way you don't need to reset migrations to a clear state neither delete .Designer files. You can always change configuration to Release and use .Designer files by any means necessary.

Comment: Yes it is something to give you some time, the real solution for the problem is a "reset" we just can't skip it.

Comment: If you want to keep only the latest migration designer files, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65004969/331281

Comment: Thank you @JaimeYule for this WONDERFULL tip. Our migrations took over 2 mins to build and after applying your suggestion, it went down to sing digit seconds.

Answer (score 0):

To reset all migrations and updates from scratch (Assume no useful data on disk), the following steps may be useful.

---

(1) Ensure that program.cs file is not optimized for creating/ updating Database by Database.EnsureCreate command, as this command prevents Migrations.
(2) Delete folder Migrations.
(3) dotnet build
(4) dotnet ef database update 0 -c yourContextFile
(5) dotnet ef migrations add init  -c yourContextFile
(6) dotnet ef database update -c yourContextFile

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP ("Assume no useful data on disk"?!)

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar task today for my project and the following are the steps I used (updated from niranjan's answer):

0. Ensure that Program.cs file is not optimized for creating/ updating Database by Database.EnsureCreate command, as this command prevents Migrations.
1. Backup target production database (in case anything goes wrong, we can restore using the backups).
2. Delete all files (incl. migration scripts and snapshot) under Migrations folder.
3. Create a new database without any objects.
4. In local development environment, change database connection string to point to the newly created empty database/
5. Use dotnet ef migrations command to generate a new migratipn. For example, `dotnet ef migrations add Rebase20230701 --startup-project  StartupProjectName --project ProjectNameThatContainsMigrations`
6. In step 5), a new migration will be generated, for example, 20230701012623_Rebase20230701.
7. Use the migration ID generated above to manually insert into local **original** database, for example `insert into dbo.__EFMigrationsHistory(MigrationId, ProductVersion) VALUES ('20230701012623_Rebase20230701','7.0.8');`. This will informs EF not to do any actual migrations. Please do keep your previous migrations records in the table.
8. Run your application locally to ensure everything works ok and no data is lost.
9. Run step 7) again in your target production environment.
10. Commit your code changes into your repo and deploy your applications into target production environment. The migrations folder should only have 20230701012623_Rebase20230701.cs and the snapshot C# files.