# .net core 2 app long build time because of migrations

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have .NET Core app where I store DBContext, Entities and Migrations. Also I have about ~1000 migrations. Building of this project lasts ~3 minutes. When I exclude Migrations folder then building lasts ~10 seconds.

What's the reason of it? Can I improve that somehow?

Comment: Remove old migrations ;) I don't believe you need all of them.

Answer (score 1):

We're having the same problem. [This github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3663) implies that it's a bug that should be fixed in later versions.
[This other stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52627277/how-to-handle-huge-efcore-migrations-designer-files-that-is-slowing-down-build-a) supposedly has a solution, but that doesn't appear to make any difference for me. Build time is still long and uses up way too many resources.