# How do you update the .designer.cs and snapshot files generated by EF Core to include manually generated tables

Tags: entity-framework-core

## Context

EF Core has a [`MigrationBuilder.CreateTable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.createtable?view=efcore-8.0) method which can be used to manually add tables that don't exist in a DbContext.

EF Core *also* has [`.Designer.cs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#add-a-migration) files for each migration which "*Contains information used by EF*" and a `...DbContextModelSnapshot.cs` file which are both generated automagically by `dotnet ef migrations add`.

## The problem

When you generate a migration by modifying your DbContext (e.g. adding a new `DbSet<SomeClass>`) and running `dotnet ef migrations add` the designer and snapshot both include the new table. But when you create an empty migration and *then* add a call to `CreateTable()` with a table name that is not in the DbContext I have found no way of getting the designer and snapshot to include the additional table.

## Questions

I have not been able to find clear documentation on what EF Core uses the designer and snapshot files for. From experimenting applying and rolling back such migrations work fine without the information in the generated files.

This leaves me with these questions that I can't answer:

1. Does it matter under any circumstances if tables are in the migration and database but not in designer and snapshot files?
2. What does EF Core (v8) actually use these files for?
3. How can one regenerated the generated files to include an accurate state (if that's even possible).

You can also [run arbitrary raw SQL in migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#adding-raw-sql) which would result in the same questions.

This [article on resolving conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/teams) hints at a way to regenerate the generated files but the ef cli doesn't have a force option.

Comment: First I would ask, why do you have empty migrations in the first place? Why can't EF pick them up when scaffolding?

Comment: They are tables used by a third-party library, so they need to exist in the database but don't need to be in the application code or dbcontext

Comment: I still don't understand, why do you want those tables in your model then?

Comment: I don't want them in the model (i.e. dbcontext or c# classes I control), but I *do* want them in the database, and because I'm using EF Core migrations to manage the database that means I need them to be created in the migration files.

Comment: But if you want them in the database and not in your model, why do you care about designer and snapshot files? I am really confused as to what your actual problem is.

Comment: "why do you care about designer and snapshot files" - the problem is that I don't know if I *should* care. From the below answer it seems it's okay to not care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snapshot file contains current Model state. It is just serialized your current Model.

> Does it matter under any circumstances if tables are in the migration and database but not in designer and snapshot files?

No. EF Core uses snapshot file to generate migrations. It do not connect to database to generate new migrations. It loads snapshot file and compares it with your current model.

1. Using difference between two models, EF Core generates migration file.
2. Old snapshot file is moved to `designer.cs`
3. Current model saved to snaphot file.

---

> How can one regenerated the generated files to include an accurate state (if that's even possible).

It is what scaffold do, generates model from databse, then serilize model to snapshot.

---

For which purpose `designer.cs` files are used for:

1. Execute migration - for Insert, Update, etc, used metadata information stored in this file and only for tables which affected in Migration file.
2. For removing last migration, yes it replaces snapshot file.

So, basically knowing how migrations generation works you can control over it.

Comment: That's excellent information, thanks. Can you link to any sources for this information, or anywhere I can learn more about this?

Comment: No books. I had task to understand how we can reduce migrations size. A lot of `designer.cs` slowdown build to several minutes. So, I've cloned EF Core repository, analysed `dotnet-ef` code and created tool which reduces size of these files. It was experiments, but knowledge remain.

Comment: Ah interesting, thanks. Someone else was asking about reducing their size here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47048721/10245

Comment: Well, comparing to my solution it is children games ;) Process was automatic, run tool and files are shrinked. For public sharing it is better to polish it or even better to include into official EF Core code.