# EF Core creating table again in second migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

So I am trying to make a new migration. I have a init migration, and I am making a second migration.

However when I create that second migration, it keeps trying to create a new table even though it already exists. It is literally the same code. The only difference is the fact that in the second migration, it is asigning the nvarchar(n) as 450 isntread of 25.

Even still that doesnt explain why it is making an entirely new table, and not just adjusting the size of the varchar.

The code is below.

```
 migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
 name: "TableName",
 columns: table => new
 {
     pk_value= table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(25)", nullable: false),
     value = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true)
 },
 constraints: table =>
 {
     table.PrimaryKey("PK_TableName", x => x.Code);
 });
```

Comment: Did you discard changes to your `DbContextModelSnapshot`? Entity Framework updates this snapshot (it's a file) after generating a migration to be up to date with the database entities. This snapshot serves as the basis for Entity Framework to generate future migrations.

Comment: So effectivly if it were to be deleted, then all future migrations I add would be asuming there was no migrations. 
Wouldn't it just be recreated every time there is a migration, and then the new values in the migration added onto that?

Comment: I have answered how [EF Core migrations works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78106677/10646316). Maybe you can understand what happened.